# How to test dates?

Tags: python-3.x

Can you tell me why this compaison code doesn't work?

```
DateStart= '16/07/2020'
DateEnd  = '24/10/2020'
   
for i in range(14,124):
    date_depart = date.today()+timedelta(days=i)
    date_retour = date.today()+timedelta(days=(i+row['duree_sejour']))
        
    if (date_depart.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') >=datetime.strptime(DateStart, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')) \
    and (date_retour.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') >=datetime.strptime(DateEnd, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')):
        print("Depearture: {}. Back: {}.".format(date_depart.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),date_retour.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
```

It returns this output:

Depearture: 18/07/2020. Back: 25/07/2020.
Depearture: 19/07/2020. Back: 26/07/2020.
Depearture: 20/07/2020. Back: 27/07/2020.
Depearture: 21/07/2020. Back: 28/07/2020.
Depearture: 22/07/2020. Back: 29/07/2020.
Depearture: 23/07/2020. Back: 30/07/2020.
Depearture: 24/07/2020. Back: 31/07/2020.
Depearture: 18/08/2020. Back: 25/08/2020.
Depearture: 19/08/2020. Back: 26/08/2020.
Depearture: 20/08/2020. Back: 27/08/2020.
Depearture: 21/08/2020. Back: 28/08/2020.
Depearture: 22/08/2020. Back: 29/08/2020.
Depearture: 23/08/2020. Back: 30/08/2020.
Depearture: 24/08/2020. Back: 31/08/2020.
Depearture: 18/09/2020. Back: 25/09/2020.
Depearture: 19/09/2020. Back: 26/09/2020.
Depearture: 20/09/2020. Back: 27/09/2020.
Depearture: 21/09/2020. Back: 28/09/2020.
Depearture: 22/09/2020. Back: 29/09/2020.
Depearture: 23/09/2020. Back: 30/09/2020.
Depearture: 17/10/2020. Back: 24/10/2020.
Depearture: 18/10/2020. Back: 25/10/2020.
Depearture: 19/10/2020. Back: 26/10/2020.
Depearture: 20/10/2020. Back: 27/10/2020.
Depearture: 21/10/2020. Back: 28/10/2020.
Depearture: 22/10/2020. Back: 29/10/2020.
Depearture: 23/10/2020. Back: 30/10/2020.
Depearture: 24/10/2020. Back: 31/10/2020.

Why do we pass directly from '24/07/2020' date to '18/08/2020'?
Thanks a lot.
Théo

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a rich comparison between `str` objects, which does not contain the appropriate logic for the chronological comparison of dates. Instead, you can do:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

date_start = date(2020, 7, 16)
date_end = date(2020, 10, 24)


for i in range(14, 124):
    date_depart = (datetime.today()+timedelta(days=i)).date()
    date_retour = (datetime.today()+timedelta(days=(i+row['duree_sejour']))).date()

    if (date_depart >= date_start) and (date_retour <= date_end):
        print("Depearture: {}. Back: {}.".format(date_depart, date_retour))
```

Here, we build `datetime.Date` objects, for which there is an explicit meaning to `<`, `>`, `<=` `>=` etc - it *understands* the chronology of dates.